# Swift JSON Get into TableViewCell

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swift3

My Data format

```
{
    "StationID": "1001",
    "StationName": {
      "Zh_tw": "基隆",
      "En": "Keelung"
    },
    "TrainNo": "1281",
    "Direction": 1,
    "TrainClassificationID": "1131",
    "TripLine": 0,
    "EndingStationID": "1025",
    "EndingStationName": {
      "Zh_tw": "新竹",
      "En": "Hsinchu"
    },
    "ScheduledArrivalTime": "22:02:00",
    "ScheduledDepartureTime": "22:04:00",
    "DelayTime": 0,
    "Platform": "",
    "SrcUpdateTime": "2017-01-24T22:14:29+08:00",
    "UpdateTime": "2017-01-24T22:14:40+08:00"
  },
```

My Code (Swift 3)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.stationID.text = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["StationID"] as? String

    let stationDirect = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["Direction"] as? Int
    if stationDirect == 0 {
        cell.stationdirection.text = "順行"
    }else{
        cell.stationdirection.text = "逆行"
    }

    cell.stationtrainNo.text = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["TrainNo"] as? String

    let stationTripline = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["TripLine"] as? Int
    if stationTripline == 0 {
        cell.stationtripLine.text = "不經山線/海線"
    }else if stationTripline == 1 {
        cell.stationtripLine.text = "山線"
    }else {
        cell.stationtripLine.text = "海線"
    }
    //cell.stationtripLine.text = String(stationTripline!)

    return cell
}
```

My question is how to get StationName, Zh_tw, and En transfer to TableView cell?

Comment: I would advise you to go off and learn about JSON serialisation. You should setup a new class and convert your JSON into swift objects and then use a model value like a class or struct to store the converted JSON in, so then it would be a lot more simplistic to populate a table view with.

Comment: If using trainStatusArray["StationName"]["Zh_tw"] will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StationName` and `EndingStationName` both are Dictionary so you can get value of `Zh_tw` like this way.

```
if let stationName = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["StationName"] as? [String:Any], 
   let zhTW = stationName ["Zh_tw"] as? String, let en = stationName ["En"] as? String { 
       cell.stationName.text = zhTW 
}else {
       cell.stationName.text = ""//Set default name
}
```

Same goes for `EndingStationName` also.

**Note:** Instead of using Array of dictionary if you create array of custom object from this dictionary it will lot easy for you assign label text in `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Yes, no used swifyJson

Comment: if let stationName = trainStatusArray[indexPath.row]["StationName"] as? [String : Any] {
            let stationZhTw = stationName["Zh_tw"] as? String
            let stationEn = stationName["En"] as? String
            
            cell.stationNameCh.text = stationZhTw
            cell.stationNameEn.text = stationEn
        }is work, now thank you Nirav

Comment: @高小高 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score -1):

First convert JSON `String` into  `Data` and again convert `Data` into  `Dictionary` form using `JSONSerialization`

**Swift 3**

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// pass your String JSON 
    let dict = convertToDictionary(text: str)
```

**Swift 2**

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

get dictonary from String

```
let dict= convertStringToDictionary(str)

if let strStationName= result?["EndingStationName"] {

  let zhTW = strStationName["Zh_tw"] as? String  

   cell.stationdirection.text=zhTW 
}
```

Comment: @Dhiry I has create function to get json data, you say this ?    func trainInOutstatusData() {
            do {
                let trainInOutstatusData = try? Data(contentsOf: trainStatusUrl!)
                let trainInOutStatusjson = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: trainInOutstatusData!, options: .mutableContainers)
                if let InOutStatus = trainInOutStatusjson as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

Comment: what are you getting `InOutStatus` ??

Comment: use  `try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }` to convert `Data` into **Dictionary**

Comment: welcome,,,,let me know if this worked for you or not ?

Comment: Dear @Dhiru I try your code, are your code get JSON data will return to function? but my code will append to other array. rainStatusArray.append(dataInOutStatus as AnyObject!)  if append to other Array what can I do this?

Comment: you can append Two `Array` not `Dictionary` with `Array`..... you can use `addObject` method to add  `Dictionary` object in array but your array Count will be increased .  @高小高

Comment: Sorry ! @Dhiru is me, I has tried your code, but I don't understand how to convert to Dictionary, look your code, you need send string too function and return back [String:Anyobject], How to get the string to send?